# Commonly Used Interaction Hamiltonian and Its Hermiticity

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hamiltonian

Please see [reference](http://www.tau.ac.il/~yakir/yahp/yh25.pdf) ("Meaning of the Density Matrix" by Anandan and Aharonov, Foundations of Physics Letters, vol. 12, No. 6, 1999) p, 573, eq. 2. I am not asking about the overall content or thoughts of that paper. I am simply wondering if the commonly used interaction hamiltonian described, in eq. 2., is Hermitian? I think it is, but want to be sure. This is similar to the interaction Hamiltonian used in the Stern Gerlach experiment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The eq. 2 formulates the interaction Hamiltonian as,
\begin{equation}
H_I=-g(t) q A,
\end{equation}
where $g(t)$ is $c$-number function, $q$ is an observable of apparatus, $A$ is an observable of the system.

You most probably have doubts about its hermiticity because for two arbirary self-adjoint operators $q$ and $A$ generally speaking, $(qA)^\dagger=Aq\neq qA$. So we see that this happens because generally speaking two observables do not commute.

However the operators are not generic. The bipartite case they consider is defined by the Hilbert space being decomposed into the tensor product $\mathcal{H}=\mathcal{H}_S\otimes\mathcal{H}_A$ of the Hilbert spaces of the states of the system and apparatus respectively. The words in the definition above (observable of apparatus/system) mean that,
\begin{equation}
q=I_S\otimes q_A,\quad A=A_S\otimes I_A,\qquad qA=Aq=A_S\otimes q_A
\end{equation}
As those operators commute you don't have the problem $(qA)^\dagger\neq qA$

Comment: Thank you. So, it is Hermitian?

Comment: @David Yep, it is